# how to update current datetime in php mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can i update new datetime in asia/manila timezone?

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE logtrail_login(
    login_id INT(100) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    admin_id INT(100),
    dateandtime_login  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    dateandtime_logout DATETIME
);
```

PHP code

```
$newdate = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

$sql1 = "UPDATE logtrail_login SET dateandtime_logout = '$newdate' WHERE login_id = $id";    
mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: By actually passing a date. Have you read the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set) for `date_default_timezone_set`? It doesn't return a date.

Comment: no errors.. i just dont know how to store the datetime

Comment: yeah, but i want it if i click the logout button the dateandtime_logout will be filled a datetime..  is it possible?

Comment: It is unclear where `$id` is defined but it does potentially leave your code open to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using `Prepared statements`

Comment: Yes, by doing exactly what @RiggsFolly suggested (getting current date and time).

Comment: sorry for the $id, i didn't post the whole code... all i want is the sysntax

Comment: `"UPDATE logtrail_login SET dateandtime_logout = now() WHERE login_id = $id"`

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to update datetime in the database.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
$newdate = time();
$sql1 = "UPDATE logtrail_login SET dateandtime_logout = '$newdate' WHERE login_id = $id";    
mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
```

Comment: Bad idea to set the timestamp in another timezone as the sql server do... your `dateandtime_login  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` stores a wrong time if the server not works with the same Timezone.

Comment: If this is a bad idea then you should also tell which one should be the best idea to define timezone.